# Estoy intentando instalar virtual box en debian y no me deja ingresar la apt-key

Tags: linux, debian, gpg

Estoy intentando descargar virtual box en linux debian y cuando ingreso el apt-key me sale esto=

```
*wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -*
gpg: no se han encontras datos OpenPGP validos
```

alguno sabe como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

El comando que empleas sale en la [documentación](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), es correcto.

Des de mi PC compruebo que el fichero existe y se puede importar:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
OK
```

El error que te sale es de `gpg`. Parece que no le sirve lo que te has descargado.

Prueba paso a paso

0. Asegura que des de un navegador puedes entrar a: `https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc`. Se trata de una llave publica al estilo

   ```
   -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
   Version: GnuPG v1.4.12 (GNU/Linux)

   mQINBFcZ9OEBEACSvycoAEIKJnyyIpZ9cZLCWa+rHjXJzPymndnPOwZr9lksZVYs
   12YnsEy7Uj48rTB6mipbIuDDH9VBybJzpu3YjY7PFTkYAeW6WAPeJ8RcSGXsDvc0
   fQ8c+7/2V1bpNofc9vDSdvcM/U8ULQcNeEa6DI4/wgy2sWLXpi1DYhuUOSU10I97
   KHPwmpWQPsLtLHEeodeOTvnmSvLX1RRl32TPFLpLdjTpkEGS7XrOEXelqzMBQXau
   ```
1. Descargar fichero manualmente :

   `wget https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc`
2. Importar llave con `apt-key`:

   ```
   sudo apt-key add oracle_vbox_2016.asc
   OK
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias!